# Routing in MVC3 - How can i call ReturnView() for a view in another folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, nopcommerce

i have a mvc3 project ( nopcommerce 2.65 ) with structure like this.

```
Nop.Plugin.Payments.KrediKarti (namespace)
--Controllers
----SecurePaymentReturnController.cs
:
:
Nop.Web (other namespace)
--Views
----Checkout
------Confirm.cshtml
```

I want to call ReturnView() method from SecurePaymentReturnController.cs for Confirm.cshtml view with its model as parameter like this "ReturnView("Confirm",model)".

But the view cannot be found by view engine. I tried these ;

```
ReturnView("Confirm",model)
ReturnView("Checkout/Confirm",model)
ReturnView("Nop.Web.Checkout.Confirm",model)
```

**How can i call this view ? What is the proper view name (or route or something) for this view ?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to declare full path to view include .cshtml extension, like this:

```
return View("~/Views/Checkout/Confirm.cshtml", model);
```

Comment: Thanks YD1m, it works like charm but with a little correction it must be return View("~/Views/Checkout/Confirm.cshtml",model);